# swift check if variable of type Data is empty

Tags: swift

I was going through docs of Data in swift from this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data

So basically what i am doing is, i am creating a variable of type data inside a function and later on putting some value in it and then returning this variable from the function like this:

```
var data = Data.init()
    //call some function which returns a data variable on success
    // and then put that variable inside this 

    // data = returnedData


return data
```

After returning this data from the function how can i check if it is empty.I couldn't find any method in the docs.

Comment: `isEmpty` – documented on the page that you linked to.

Answer (score 8):

```
var data = Data.init()
    //call some function which returns a data variable on success
    // and then put that variable inside this 

    // data = returnedData


return data
```

In this case you variable `data` will never be `nil` because you are instatiating  it. What you need to do is to check if it's empty or not.

```
if data.isEmpty {
  print("data is empty")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check with the `isEmpty` property

```
if (data.isEmpty) {
        print("Data is empty")
    }
```

Comment: data == nil is wrong. they assined value to that variable

Comment: data will never be nil. Must check if it is empty

Comment: @AkshanshThakur yes agree that's why i have posted two ways :)

Comment: actually, it might give compiler error because data is not an optional. So equating it to nil is technically wrong.

Comment: `data.isEmpty` without the parentheses. It is a (computed) property, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

Call the is `isEmpty` upon your return

```
if data.isEmpty {
  // nothing returned
}
```

Comment: `data.isEmpty` without the parentheses. It is a (computed) property, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

You just check

```
if data.count == 0 { 
      // empty
} else {
     /// data not empty
     // In fact, count is equivalent to bytes of data
}
```

Comment: yes agree this is also a great way to check it is empty or not

Comment: @MaheshDangar "this is also a great way" NO. You should never use the count property to check if a collection is empty

Comment: Never use the number of bytes to check if Data is empty. There is the `isEmpty` property for this purpose.